# How do I view Transport Type Configuration in BizTalk Send Port (e.g. Content of Bindings.xml)?

Tags: powershell, configuration, binding, certificate, biztalk

I am trying to view the transport type configuration properties of Send Port in BizTalk.

I have download BizTalk PowerShell extensions. I am able to view the item property of the transport type configuration of a specific send port.

For example (where my send port name is "SP_Testing")

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy –ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Add-PSSnapin –Name BiztalkFactory.Powershell.Extensions
cd 'BizTalk:\All Artifacts\Send Ports'
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'SP_Testing'
```

What I am expecting is being able to look at the configuration of the transport type WCF-Custom. However, what I am getting is just a general property of the send-port.

[image]

In the Biztalk Admin Console, there is a button within the Send Port Properties my question is how do I navigate to this button in PowerShell? The properties that I need is after clicking the "Configure" button
[image]

Comment: In other words, I want to see the content of the bindings via powershell.

Comment: What is you ultimate goal here?  Adapter configuration is entirely custom so there's no model for ps to work with easily.

Comment: Hello John. Thanks for the reply. My goal here is to ultimately read the contents of the transport WCF Custom properties. So if you click on "Configure" from the screenshot, I want to be able to read the contents within that gooey.

Comment: Well, sure, but just reading the config doesn't get you anything.  What actions will this drive?

Answer (score 0):

There is a powershell command for exporting the binding, you can check all the command by running below command:

```
Get-Command | where { $_.ModuleName -like "BizTalk*" }
```

[image]

You can check the Export Binding complete implementation [here](https://blogs.biztalk360.com/biztalk-bindings-exportation-how-to-export-biztalk-server-bindings-by-a-list-of-port-names-with-powershell/).
Hope it helps.

Comment: I get that we can export the bindings. But I want to know if we can view the content of the bindings via BiztalkFactory.Powershell.Extensions